# how to add dynamic variables as attribute of a class in PYTHON

Tags: python

I have a class with dynamic variable i want to make them as attribute of my class

```
class test:
      def __init__(self):
            for i in range(10):
                    globals()["var"+str(i)]=i
```

I tried this method but it doesn't work

```
class test:
      def __init__(self):
            for i in range(10):
                    globals()["self.var"+str(i)]=i
```

Comment: There are no variables in this code at all.  What are you actually trying to do?  Why not just put the variables in the class?

Comment: Just use `self.var = list(range(10))` and acccess with `t = test(); t.var[0]`, etc.  Whenever you feel the need to make numbered variables, use a list.

Answer (score 2):

```py
class test:
      def __init__(self):
            for i in range(10):
                    setattr(test, "var"+str(i), i)


x = test()
```

Comment: While this works, it is a horrible practice.  Use a list.